# Python Script Read RFComm Data

Tags: python, pi-3, serial, bluetooth

I have successfully paired the Pi 3 to an Android phone via bluetooth. I have tested an RFcomm channel connection using Bluetooth Terminal from the Play Store and it shows that I have a valid connection for data transport.

Now I simply want to view the data from a Python script. Very basic, just read from the port and print. Here's the code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('dev/rfcomm0', 9600)

while True:
    result = ser.read()
    print result
```

I get an error however when I run this code:

SerialException: could not open port dev/rfcomm0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dev/rfcomm0'

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error said, you have the wrong path. Did you missed `/` at first?
`/dev/rfcomm0`?

Anyway, the bluetooth serial port of RPi 3 is on `/dev/ttyAMA0`, maybe you should try that first.

Comment: Yes, I had figured that out almost immediately after posting that I was simply missing the / .. Once I fixed that I easily could read incoming bits from the Bluetooth Terminal app. I didn't have to change the port.